# label and caption the graphs

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels, graphs

Here in the picture has $3$ figures I want to caption them differently and label them differently. Can you please suggest what should I do.

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3, every loop/.style={}]

    \vertex[fill] (1) at (0, 1)  [label=above: 1] {}; 

 \vertex [fill](2) at (.5,1.5) [label=left: 2] {};

\vertex[fill] (3) at (1,.3) [label=left: 3]{};

  \vertex[fill] (4) at (.7,0) [label=right: 4] {}; 

    \vertex[fill] (5) at (1, 1) [label=above: 5][label=right: 4 \hspace{.5cm}\mbox{$=$}]  {}; 

    \vertex [fill](6) at (1.3,.5) [label=left: 6][label=below: 10] {};

    \vertex[fill] (7) at (1.6, 1)  [label=above: 1] {}; 

 \vertex [fill](8) at (2.1,1.5) [label=left: 2] {};

\vertex[fill] (9) at (2.6,.3) [label=left: 3]{};

  \vertex[fill] (10) at (2.3,0) [label=right: 4][label=below: 1] {};  

    \vertex[fill] (11) at (2.6, 1) [label=above: 5][label=right:3 \hspace{.5cm}\mbox{$-$}]  {};  

    \vertex [fill](12) at (2.9,.5) [label=left: 6][label=below: 10] {};

 \vertex[fill] (13) at (3.2, 1)  [label=above: 1] {}; 

 \vertex [fill](14) at (3.7,1.5) [label=left: 2] [label=above: 1]{};

\vertex[fill] (15) at (4.2,.3) [label=below: 3]{};

  \vertex[fill] (16) at (3.9,0) [label=right: 4] {}; 

    \vertex[fill] (17) at (4.2, 1) [label=above: 5][label=right:3]  {}; 

    \vertex [fill](18) at (4.5,.5) [label=left: 6][label=below: 10] {}; 

 \draw (1.3,.5)  to[in=-50,out=-130,loop] (5,1);

 \draw (2.9,.5)  to[in=-50,out=-130,loop] (5,1);

   \draw (2.3,0)  to[in=-50,out=-130,loop] (5,1);

  \draw (2.6,1)  to[in=30,out=-70,loop] (2.6,1);

  \draw (1,1)  to[in=30,out=-70,loop] (1,1);

  \draw (3.7,1.5)  to[in=130,out=10,loop] (4,1);

  \draw (4.2,1)  to[in=30,out=-70,loop] (4.2,1);

  \draw (4.5,.5)  to[in=-50,out=-130,loop] (4.5,.5);
    \path


        (1) edge node [below] {5} (3)
        (1) edge node [below] {2} (2)
        (1) edge node [below] {3} (4)
        (2) edge node [right] {7} (4)
        (2) edge node [above] {1} (5)
        (5) edge node [right] {5} (3)
        %(3) edge node [right] {1} (6)
        (7) edge node [below] {2} (8)
        (7) edge node [below] {5} (9)
        (7) edge node [below] {3} (10)
        (8) edge node [right] {6} (10)
        (8) edge node [right] {2} (11)
        (9) edge node [right] {5} (11)
        (13) edge node [below] {5} (15)
        (13) edge node [below] {2} (14)
        (13) edge node [below] {3} (16)
        (14) edge node [right] {6} (16)
        (14) edge node [above] {1} (17)
        (17) edge node [right] {5} (15)
        (16) edge node [above] {1} (17)
        ;  

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}

\hspace{1.5cm}Figure $1$
\hspace{3.5cm}Figure $2$
\hspace{3.5cm}Figure $3$
```

Comment: Draw in three different `tikzpicture`s and put each of them inside a `figure` environment, and add `\caption` and `\label` inside each environment. Please show a compilable code.

Comment: I want them in a row. So I have drawn them in one tikzpicture

Comment: Alright, first of all please make your code compilable. If you want them to be in a row, you can use `subfigure` environment from `subcaption` package. To literally label each diagram you _must_ draw each picture in an individual `tikzpicture`. There are workarounds though, but I dislike workarounds (and hopefully so do you).

Comment: BTW,. I could not find \vertex in the PGF manual nor in any of the packages I currently have installed.

Comment: @JohnKormylo `tikz-feynman` has this command. To get a working code, load `\usepackage{tikz-feynman}` and wrap the `\vertex` commands in `\begin{feynman} ... \end{feynman}`.